# NGINX FastCGI Cache on NGINX > Apache > PHP-FPM

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apache-2.4, php-fpm, cache

I had failed attempts earlier at getting Nginx Fast-CGI caching to work in `Nginx > Apache > PHP-FPM` config so I started fresh on a new server but am still having issues.

The server has a clean `Ubuntu 16.04` install with `Nginx 1.14.2`, `Apache 2.4.18` and `PHP-FPM 5.6` (just for testing sake).

My `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` config is stock as I've only made changes in vhost (anything outside server block is effectively `nginx.conf`).

My apache2 test.mysite.com.conf is

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
        ServerName test.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/
</VirtualHost>
```

To test caching, I have following in `/var/www/cachetest.php`

```
<?php
echo time();
?>
```

However testing `http://test.mysite.com/cachetest.php` changes every second and consequently `/etc/nginx/cache` is always empty (its `777` for now).

**Any ideas why cache isn't working?**

Answer (score 1):

You can't `fastcgi_cache` because you never `fastcgi_pass` to PHP-FPM.

In nginx, the cache is attached to a specific method of sending requests upstream, e.g. fastcgi, proxy, uwsgi, etc.

You can either use a `proxy_cache` instead, or better yet, just `fastcgi_pass` to PHP-FPM directly from nginx, and get rid of Apache as it's redundant.